# Read XML texts into tibble

Tags: r, xml, tidyverse

I want to take an xml file (which I'm calling "2019-05-24.xml") like this:

```xml
<file>
    <header>
        <filename>2019-05-24</filename>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div type="article">
            <head>First test article</head>
            <p>Some information.</p>
            <p>Some other information.</p>
        </div>
        <div type="section" feature="essay">
            <head>Test essay</head>
            <p>An argument.</p>
            <p>Supporting evidence.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</file>
```

and turn it into a tibble like this

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  filename        seq type    feature head       text                                                                    
  <chr>         <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>      <chr>                                                                  
1 2019-05-24.xml    1 article NA      First test "Some information. Other information. Yet…
2 2019-05-24.xml    2 section essay   Test essay "An argument. Supporting evidence."                              
3 2019-05-24.xml    3 index   NA      NA         "Article.....1 Essay....2"
```

This gets me partway there:

```
sample <- "2019-05-24.xml"

extract_data <- function(x){
  divs <- x %>% 
    read_xml() %>%
    xml_child(2) %>%
    xml_find_all(".//div")
  text <- xml_text(divs)
  type <- xml_attr(divs, "type")
  feature <- xml_attr(divs, "feature")
  seq <- seq_along(divs)
  test_tibble <- tibble(filename = x, seq = seq, type = type, feature = feature, text = text)
}

lapply(sample, extract_data)
```

Unfortunately, the result concatenates the `head` and the `p` text:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  filename       seq type    feature text                                                       
  <chr>        <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>                                                      
1 2019-05-24.…     1 article NA      "First test articleSome information.\n            Other in…
2 2019-05-24.…     2 section essay   Test essayAn argument.Supporting evidence.                 
3 2019-05-24.…     3 index   NA      Article.....1Essay....2
```

### Problem 1: head

If I extract the `head` in the same way I extracted the text

```
head <- sample %>% 
  read_xml() %>%
  xml_child(2) %>%
  xml_find_all(".//div/head//text()")
```

I get an error due because there the third `div` contains no `head`:

```
Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 2: Column `head`
* Length 3: Columns `seq`, `type`, `feature`
```

Can I get this function to return `NA` if there is not `head` in a `div`?

### Problem 2: Reading text within a div

I want to read only the text within each of the three items or nodes on the `divs` list. Can I make something like `text <- divs %>% xml_children %>% xml_text()` (which returns every child in the whole file) work on each node individually? I've tried various `apply()` variants. I think I'm doing something wrong with XPath and `xml_find_all` and `xml_text`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, needed to parse each div individually, then create a list of data frames and then cbind everything together.

```
library(xml2)
library(tibble)

sample <- "2019-05-24.xml"

extract_data <- function(x){
  #read file
  file<-read_xml(x)
  #extract divs, get type attribute and 
  divs <- file %>% xml_find_all(".//div")
  type <- xml_attr(divs, "type")

  #find the head and p for each div
  #returns a list of data frames
  output<-lapply(divs, function(d){
    header<- d %>% xml_find_first(".//head") %>% xml_text()
    text<-d %>% xml_find_all(".//p") %>% xml_text() %>%  paste( collapse = ", ")
    data.frame(head=header, text)
  })
  #bind everything up into a tibble.
  answer<-do.call(rbind, output)
  test_tibble <- cbind(tibble(filename = x, seq = 1:nrow(answer), type = type), answer)
}

lapply(sample, extract_data)



#[[1]]
        filename seq    type               head                                       text
#1 2019-05-24.xml   1 article First test article Some information., Some other information.
#2 2019-05-24.xml   2 section         Test essay         An argument., Supporting evidence.
```

Comment: This does what I need--thanks!--but I still don't quite understand why we need the last two lines of the function to be what they are. Why is `output`/`answer` different from the other columns of the tibble, requiring it to be added using `cbind`? I guess it's because a list can't be added directly to a tibble, so its rows must be bound together first? Sorry to ask a simplistic question.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, how is the list generated by `divs` different from the list generated by `output`?

Comment: @WillHanley, good questions.  The variable "output" is a list of dataframes (in this case all with just  a single row), thus the  function `do.call` concatenates the list of data frames into a single data frame ("answer") with multiple rows and the columns 'head' and 'text'.  The last line of the function  , `cbind` adds the 'filename', 'sequence' and 'type' columns onto the 'head', 'text' columns.  I hope this helps. To visualize this better try adding a few print statements to the function